# Classic ASP (VBScript) Display only first image (YouTube image)

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, youtube

This is my first time posting here - it's a great resource, I keep seeming to find solutions on here.  I'm writing code to display an image gallery of YouTube videos on a website.  I'm using Classic ASP to parse the RSS feed, and so far I've successfully got the thumbnail of the YouTube video.  Now I'm trying to display only one of the 4 Jpegs - the URL of the YouTube RSS for thumbnails seems to be in the following format:

1. http://i.ytimg.com/vi/oh_OMkstzMQ/0.jpg
2. http://i.ytimg.com/vi/oh_OMkstzMQ/1.jpg
3. http://i.ytimg.com/vi/oh_OMkstzMQ/2.jpg
4. http://i.ytimg.com/vi/oh_OMkstzMQ/3.jpg

So, I was wondering if someone could suggest a way to only get `0.jpg` from the feed?  I'll post my code below:

```
<%
Dim xml, xhr, ns, YouTubeID, TrimmedID, GetJpeg, GetJpeg2, GetJpeg3, thumbnailUrl, xmlList, nodeList, TrimmedThumbnailUrl
Set xml = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument")
xml.async = False
xml.setProperty "ServerHTTPRequest", True
xml.Load("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/Shuggy23/favorites?orderby=updated")
If xml.parseError.errorCode <> 0 Then
    Response.Write xml.parseError.reason
End If
Set xmlList = xml.getElementsByTagName("entry")
Set nodeList = xml.SelectNodes("//media:thumbnail")
For Each xmlItem In xmlList
    YouTubeID = xmlItem.getElementsByTagName("id")(0).Text
    TrimmedID = Replace(YouTubeID, "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/", "")
    For Each xmlItem2 In nodeList
        thumbnailUrl = xmlItem2.getAttribute("url")

        Response.Write thumbnailUrl & "<br />"
    Next    
Next    
%>
```

Hope someone can help.
Thanks very much.

Douglas

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get 0.jpg from the thumbnail URL, try:

```
Right(thumbnailUrl, Len(thumbnailUrl) - InStrRev(thumbnailUrl, "/"))
```

If you want to just get the first thumbnail, you could use `Exit For` to bail out of the loop.